# Wrap PHPWord on bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php, phpword

I just want to use PHPWord for Symfony 2. But Im new on Symfony 2.

I paste PHPWord source into my util folder bundle but there is an error loading autoloader class from PHPWord...

Question is simple, How can I "wrap" code (in this case PHPWord) in to bundle? or someway I can use it.

Any solution?

---

Thanks for answering, that gives me some light. Altough, This doen't work for me.
I download composer.phar and I edit my composer.json as you say: adding in my require region "phpword/phpword": "0.6.2" and creating new repository phpword...

Doesn't work, I run "php composer.phar" command but It doesn't download anything...

Any tutorial or tip to make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be copying the source code yourself. Use composer to install PHPWord.

Since PHPWord doesn't use composer (yet), you'll need to define a repository in your composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpword/phpword": "0.6.2"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "phpword/phpword",
                "version": "0.6.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=phpword&DownloadId=138035&FileTime=129545976016270000&Build=19692",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["."]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Than you'll be able to use PHPWord in your Symfony project (any PHP project in fact):

```
$word = new PHPWord();
$writer = new PHPWord_Writer_Word2007($word);
$writer->save('test.doc');
```

**Update**: I just realized the URL to download changes with time. It'd be better to replace it with something that doesn't change (if possible, otherwise host it somewhere yourself).

Answer (score 4):

`composer require phpoffice/phpword dev-master` did the work for me.

It should download and place install PhpOffice\PHPWord under the `vendor` folder in your Symfony2 installation (besides modifying your composer.json automatically).

In the controller you are about to `use` PhpWord:

`use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;`

And inside the action, you can create a new instance as follows:

`$doc = new PhpWord();`

Answer (score 0):

As the URL changes, you can use the github repository if you've no problem with the dev version :

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpword/phpword": "dev"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "phpword/phpword",
                "version": "dev",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/archive/develop.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["."]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple bundle as wrapper for PhpWord:
https://packagist.org/packages/ggggino/wordbundle

Comment: Thank you for answering!